# Fast searching for DVD title in IMDB data

Tags: postgresql

I would like to link my DVD collection to IMDb titles. For that, I imported the title_basics tsv into a Postgres database as one table. The data is here:

https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz

This table has almost 10 million rows.

I then create a gin index on the primaryTitle column:

`CREATE INDEX t_gin ON title_basics USING gin(primarytitle gin_trgm_ops);`

The next step is to just look for best matching title via:

```sql
SELECT  tconst, primarytitle
FROM title_basics
ORDER BY similarity(primarytitle, 'The Shape of Water 2017') DESC
limit 10
;
```

This query takes almost 30 secs. So, I'm wondering if there are any ways to improve the performance?

Here is the execution plan of the query:

```
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Limit  (cost=284857.53..284858.70 rows=10 width=34) (actual time=27975.751..27976.745 rows=10 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=693 read=142357
   I/O Timings: read=377.006
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=284857.53..1248938.24 rows=8262972 width=34) (actual time=27975.750..27976.742 rows=10 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=693 read=142357
         I/O Timings: read=377.006
         ->  Sort  (cost=283857.50..294186.22 rows=4131486 width=34) (actual time=27970.078..27970.079 rows=8 loops=3)
               Sort Key: (similarity(primarytitle, 'The Shape of Water 2017'::text)) DESC
               Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               Buffers: shared hit=693 read=142357
               I/O Timings: read=377.006
               Worker 0:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               Worker 1:  Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on title_basics  (cost=0.00..194577.58 rows=4131486 width=34) (actual time=0.047..26837.286 rows=3305189 loops=3)
                     Buffers: shared hit=577 read=142357
                     I/O Timings: read=377.006
 Planning:
   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning Time: 0.123 ms
 Execution Time: 27976.770 ms
(22 rows)
```

I'm using `PostgreSQL 14.3 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6), 64-bit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get trigram index usage using the functional form.  You need to use the operational form.

You could build the gist trigram index, then use the KNN implementation:

```
ORDER BY primarytitle <-> 'The Shape of Water 2017'
LIMIT 10
```

Or you could just impose a cutoff on how dissimilar you are willing to tolerate, and sort the results of that, accepting less than 10 results if there are fewer things that meet your cutoff:

```
WHERE primarytitle % 'The Shape of Water 2017'
ORDER BY primarytitle <-> 'The Shape of Water 2017'
LIMIT 10
```

This could use either the gin or the gist index structure.

I tend to use the second approach, as I usually find gin is better than gist for trigram indexes.

Comment: Thanks! Is the index built correctly? When I run `
select tconst, primarytitle
from title_basics
where primarytitle % 'the shape of water 2017'
order by primarytitle <-> 'the shape of water 2017'
limit 10` It's now down to 13 secs.

Comment: Actually subsequent queries are now really fast. As in subsecond!